# Mysql where clause comparison give different result for double and float data type for same value

Tags: mysql

My mysql version is 5.7.14

I have 1 table with two column

1). price_val_float with float data type

2). price_val_double with double data type

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 price_val_float FLOAT(6,2), 
 price_val_double DOUBLE(6,2)
);
```

Same value in both column

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(78.59, 78.59), 
(78.60, 78.60), 
(78.61, 78.61);
```

Now I set one variable as follow

```
SET @priceValue=78.6;
```

Now I want to get all record from test table where price_val_float >= @priceValue;

```
SELECT price_val_float FROM test WHERE price_val_float>= @priceValue;
```

above query return only **78.61**

But if I run same query of **price_val_double** column

```
SELECT price_val_double FROM test WHERE price_val_double>= @priceValue;
```

This return

```
78.60

78.61
```

I am not getting **why mysql return different result** as only **data type is different**.

Does anyone knows about this ?

Here is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea8927/1) for testing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound strange to say but this is because decimal numbers are approximates values.  This is an issue across all programming due to the nature of storing large numbers.  Even the mysql documentation calls these "approximate" values:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html

For example: MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.

This is explained in the mysql documentation here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-float.html

Or as an additional case explained in Python here:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

The way to get around this is identify the precision you want and store the value as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Float is a single precision and Double is for double precision that why your getting the difference.

Comment: Are you sure, because I am storing same value in both column and both looks same, check I provided fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the difference between the numbers shows up around the tenth decimal or so, depending on factors such as computer architecture or the compiler version or optimization level. For example, different CPUs may evaluate floating-point numbers differently.

You need to use `DECIMAL` data type for more accurate results. Also check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

That is because Float point values are not stored as exact values. If you need exact value you can use Decimal data type. You can read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)